# Missing nvarchar columns when reading SQL Server database table from Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a SQL Server database with a table that has a column of `nvarchar(4000)` data type. When I try to read the data from Oracle through a dblink, I don't see the `nvarchar(4000)` column. All the other column's data is displayed properly.

Can anyone help me to find the issue here and how to fix it?

Comment: Which driver you are using  For dbLink ?

Comment: @CoderofCode I'm sorry, i am not aware of it. DB Admin who did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Appendix A-1 ...
>
> ODBC Oracle Comment
>
> SQL_WCHAR NCHAR -
> SQL_WVARCHAR
> NVARCHAR - SQL_WLONGVARCHAR LONG if Oracle DB Character Set = Unicode.
> Otherwise, it is not supported

Commonly `nvarchar(max)` is mapped to `SQL_WLONGVARCHAR` and this data type can only be mapped to Oracle if the Oracle database character set is `unicode`.

To check the database character set, please excuet:

```
select * from nls_parameters;
```

and have a look at: `NLS_CHARACTERSET`

---

**UPDATE**

`NLS_CHARACTERSET` needs to be a `unicode` character set - for example `AL32UTF8`(Do this if you know what you are doing or ask you r DBA to do it.)

`NCHAR` character set isn't used as the mapping is to Oracle `LONG` which uses the normal database character set.

A 2nd solution would be to create on the SQL Server side a view that splits the `nvarchar(max)` to several `nvarchar(xxx)` and then to select from the view and to concatenate the content again in Oracle.(If you have problem with changing the character set to unicode then this approach is the beset way to go.)

Comment: it is NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1