# Some columns are missing in select * from Oracle to SQL Server over dblink

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to get some data out of a SQL Server instance and into an Oracle 11g database. The Oracle DB communicates wih the SQL Server over dblink.

When I try to select * from a table on the SQL Server side which has nvarchar(max) columns, those columns do not appear. They are simply ignored and not returned by the Oracle query engine.

I've come across [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28209518/missing-nvarchar-columns-when-reading-sql-server-database-table-from-oracle) but I don't think it answers my problem seeing the DB characterset on the Oracle DB's side is WE8ISO8859P15 (Unicode).

What am i missing?

Comment: Are you sure [WE8ISO8859P15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) is Unicode?
 [See the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch6unicode.htm#NLSPG316)

Comment: Are the values not returned or are the columns themselves not in the query result?
What if you explicitly query those columns in your select statement?

Comment: @Rene The columns aren't in the query reult when I `SELECT *`. If i try to explicitly selec one of these columns Oracle returns `ORA-00904: Invalid identifier"`

Comment: Maybe you have to put the column names in quotes? select "caseSensitivename" from sqlserver?

Comment: @DylanW80 - I still don't see why this isn't the same problem as the question you linked to... can you cast the missing column to varchar2 instead of nvarchar as part of the query? (Possibly not a full solution as it will be nvarchar for a reason and can presumably have characters that varchar doesn't support, but maybe worth testing).